# Finding last word inside hashes in a document, using Emacs Evil Mode

Tags: evil

I've a document I'm editing, were I want to search for the next occurrence of the last word that appears within a pair of hashes. Some examples would be:

```
 #word#, #x(anotherWord)#, #y(x(yetAnotherWord))#
```

I want to ignore the surrounding functions and brackets.

I'm new to Vim key bindings and am not clear on how to do it either in evil or holy modes.

Comment: Please do not post your question to both SE.emacs and StackOverflow. Please delete one of the posts. Thx.

Comment: Done. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/\b\w+\Sw*#[^#<C-q C-j>]*$<RET>
```

This should work in evil, whereby `<C-q C-j>` and `<RET>` are key-sequences.

Unless, what you really want to do is searching for symbols rather than words.

Here is an explanation of the regular-expression's components.

```el
\b               ;beginning of a word
\w+              ;one or more word character
\Sw*             ;zero or more non-word character
#                ;a single '#' character
[^#<C-q C-j>]*   ;0 or more arbitrary character, except '#' and '\n'
$                ;end of line
```

Comment: Thank you --- that's some crazy Emac-fu. You're helped me a great deal.